# RegEx match string between known strings and after a known text with line breaks

Tags: c#, .net, regex

So, I have this text:

```
<a href="/find/1">testing</a>
<strong>a known text</strong>
<p>testing2</p>
<p>this paragraphs are dynamically</p>
...
<a href="/find/2/">testing again</a>
<a href="/find/3/">testing and again</a>
```

I want to get all the hrefs that are under the **a known text**

I use this regex to get all the matches: `(?<=<a\ href=")/find/.*?(?=")`
But I also get the result: **/find/1** which is a result that I don't want.

I've tried this: `a known tex[\w\W](?<=<a\ href=")/find/*?(?=")` but it's not working. I have no idea how to get this done correctly. Basically I want to get only **/find/2/** and **/find/3**

PS: I am not really using C# but a software that is made in C# and uses the C# regex.

Comment: I hate to be a stickler here, but please don't parse HTML with regexes: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: I know, I usually parse it with Html Agility Pack for C#. But I really can't use it this time. It's not a big software, just something easy, but I don't know regex enough I guess

Comment: Yeah, if you can avoid it, do it. Still, the snippet seems "flat" enough. Anyway, you need to account for all the characters between the "known text" and the tag you wish to find. Perhaps `a known text(.|\n)*(?<=<a\ href=")/find/*?(?=")` would work for your case?

Comment: Thanks @MarcinŁoś but it's not really working

Comment: How about a version lazily matching the `(.|\n)*`, like `a known text(.|\n)*?(?<=<a\ href=")/find/*?(?=")` ?

Comment: nope... also not working

Comment: Ok, my previous comments were really, really dumb. `(?<=a\ known\ text(.|\n)*<a\ href=")/find/.*?(?=")` is my last shot. Requires arbitrary lookbehind though, not sure if C# implementation supports it - many don't.

Comment: He he:D works! you can post it as an answer, and i will accept it

Answer (score 1):

I have this regex, which is a bit different from Marcin's but I'm not used to have variable length regex in lookbehinds:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?:a known text|(?<!^)\G)[\w\W]+?((?<=<a\ href="")/find/.*?(?=""))");
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/X4Av9o)

Which is believe should make the regex a little bit more efficient.

`\G` is a special character which matches where the previous match ended, so that after finding the first `/find/`, it tries matching again. I had to put a negative lookbehind to prevent it from matching newline as well.

```
a known tex[\w\W](?<=<a\ href=")/find/*?(?=")
```

Concerning your regex, some little mistakes you made was to forget the quantifier for `[\w\W]` and the dot for `*?` after `/find/`. Using `a known tex[\w\W]+(?<=<a\ href=")(/find/.*?)(?=")` would have got you only `/find/2/`, which is already better than nothing!

EDIT: As AlanMoore rightly pointed out, you can simplify the regex:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?:a known text|(?<!^)\G)[\w\W]+?<a href=""(/find/.*?)""");
```

And to make the `.` match newlines, we can use `(?s)` and remove the `[\w\W]` part:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?s)(?:a known text|(?<!^)\G).*?<a href=""(/find/.*?)""");
```

Comment: This task isn't a good fit for lookbehinds, variable-width or not.  Fortunately, with your approach you don't need to use lookbehinds at all.  Check it: `@"(?s)(?:a known text|(?<!^)\G).*?<a href=""(/find/.*?)"""`

Comment: @AlanMoore Good point. I think I was trying to stick with OP's regex too much ^^;